# How to check if SQL records are identical including spaces?

Tags: mysql, sql

I realized a few records in my SQL database have an extra whitespace in them, but I'm not sure which ones have this extra whitespace. I'm trying to find which records are the same, but the statement I'm using does not differentiate records if they have an extra space at the end.

Currently I'm using the following SQL statement to check if the records are equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME='TEST ';
```

This would return records which have the name 'TEST'. How do I find which records have the name 'TEST '?

Comment: What is the datatype for name?  char? (which will pad w/ spaces?)

Comment: The datatype is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table that has multiple rows of similar data, but with random white spaces and other junk stuff laying around it, and you want to check out how much of each specific odd data you have, you can do a grouping with a count.

```
SELECT Name
       ,Last Name
       ,Count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY NAME
         ,LAST NAME
```

This should display all your results with how many of each next to it.

IE:`JOHN SMITH 2 
    JACK SMITH  1`

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky because of the way that databases handle spaces.  If you don't want to deal with different situations (does `LIKE` behave the same way? can `regexp` handle this), then you could do:

```
WHERE CONCAT(NAME, 'x') = 'TEST x';
```

Do note that the this could affect performance, if the query is able to use an index on `NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
     SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TRIM(NAME)='TEST';
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find which records have the name 'TEST '?

One way is:

```
select * from mytable   
WHERE NAME='TEST ' and length(NAME) = length('TEST ');
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of it that way, it's clever.